# Reading from rotating log files in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

As per the [documentation of logstash's `file` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html), the section on [File Rotation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_file_rotation) says the following:

> To support programs that write to the rotated file for some time after
>   the rotation has taken place, **include both the original filename and
>   the rotated filename (e.g. /var/log/syslog and /var/log/syslog.1) in
>   the filename patterns** to watch (the path option).

If anyone can clarify how to specify two filenames in the `path` configuration, that will be of great help as I did not find an exact example.   Some examples suggest to use wild-cards like `/var/log/syslog*`, however I am looking for an example that achieves exactly what is said in documentation - two filenames in the `path` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute `path` is an array and thus you can specify multiple files as follows:

```
input {
   file{
       path => [ "/var/log/syslog.log", "/var/log/syslog1.log"]
   }
}
```

You can also use `*` notation for name or directory as follows:

```
input {
   file{
       path => [ "/var/log/syslog.log", "/var/log/syslog1.log", "/var/log/*.log", "/var/*/*.log"]
   }
}
```

When you specify path as `/var/*/*.log` it does a recursive search to get all files with `.log` extension.

Reference [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html#array)